# A value of type 'T?' can't be returned from the method 'readOrCreateModel' because it has a return type of 'Future<T>'

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, types

In the code below, why is T not inferred as non nullable?

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
  Future<T?> read(String id);
  Future<T> createModel(String id);
  Future<T> readOrCreateModel(String id) async {
    T? model = await read(id);
    model ??= await createModel(id);
    return model;
  }
}
```

[image]

But if I don't use generic type, it infers correctly ?

```
abstract class Foo {
  Future<int?> read(String id);
  Future<int> createModel(String id);
  Future<int> readOrCreateModel(String id) async {
    int? model = await read(id);
    model ??= await createModel(id);
    return model;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a bug (or a limitation with type promotion with generic type arguments).  Note that your code could be simplified to `return model ?? await createModel(id);`, which *is* accepted because it avoids the assignment.  Or simplified further to `return await read(id) ?? await createModel(id);`

Comment: Aggee with. @jamesdlin